# Calling groups of string digits using grepl

Tags: r, regex, string, substring, grouping

I'm using the grepl function to try and sort through data; all the row numbers are different survey respondents, and each number in the "ANI_type" string represents a different type of animal - I need to sort these depending on animal type. More specifically, I need to group some of the digits in the strings into categories. For example, digits 6,7,8,9,10,11 all need to be placed in the animals$pock object. How would I go about that using the grep function?

```
> animals$dogs <- as.numeric(grepl("\\b1\\b", animals$ANI_type))
> animals
                                                    ANI_type dogs cats repamp
1                              1,2,5,12,13,14,15,16,18,19,27    1    1      0
2                                                          2    0    1      0
3                                             20,21,22,23,26    0    0      0
4                                                20,21,22,23    0    0      0
5                                                         13    0    0      0
6                                                          2    0    1      0
7                                                   20,21,22    0    0      0
8                                                20,21,22,23    0    0      0
9                                                   20,21,22    0    0      0
10                                             5,20,21,22,27    0    0      0
11                                              1,2,20,21,22    1    1      0
12                                       5,18,20,21,22,23,26    0    0      0
13                                                     20,21    0    0      0
14                                                        21    0    0      0
15                                                     20,21    0    0      0
16                                                  20,21,26    0    0      0
17                                                         2    0    1      0
18                                                       1,2    1    1      0
19                                                         2    0    1      0
20                                                       3,4    0    0      1
```

The expected output is the columns (dog, cat, repamp) above... these were easy to do as there is only one digit; what I'm having trouble with is splitting up multiples.

Comment: Can you add your expected output?

Comment: The expected output is the columns (dog, cat, repamp) above... these were easy to do as there is only one digit; what I'm having trouble with is splitting up multiples.

Comment: But where is it defined that which number is.what? What I mean to say is how do you know that 2 should go into `cats` and 1 should be `dogs`? Where is that information?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. All of this is from survey data; I have all of that information in a separate spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` solution could be employed with `mutate()` and `if_else()` from the `dplyr` library, and `grepl()`, for example:

```
animals <- animals %>%
  mutate(dogs = if_else(grepl("\\b1\\b|\\b22\\b", ANI_TYPE),
         cats = if_else(grepl("\\b2\\b|\\b31\\b", ANI_TYPE))
```

In this case, you'd want to separate all the different potential codes for each animal using the pipe operator `|` which functions as an `OR` operator in `R`.